My hard drive keeps disconnecting: what can the issue be?
My configuration:

Seagate Exos X22 20TB SATA 6Gb/s 7200RPM 3.5-inch Enterprise HDD (ST20000NM004E) (pic) connected via SABRENT USB 3.0 to SATA External Hard Drive Lay-Flat Docking Station (pic)
attached via USB to an Anker 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub (pic).
laptop MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH (mirror) with Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

My Seagate hard drive keeps disconnecting: what can the issue be? I tried using different USB ports on the laptop, directly connecting to the laptop's USB port without using the Anker 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub, as well as rebooting the laptop, but the issue persists.

I've ruled out the following:

Overheating: I'm looking at the disk temperature with CrystalDiskInfo, it maxes out at 48 degrees celsius, which is deemed "good" by CrystalDiskInfo. I also don't notice any correlation between the disk temperature and the disconnection likelihood.
Faulty USB port: the disconnection issues happens regardless of which USB port the disk is connected to.
Interference with other devices: I tried disconnecting all devices from the laptop  except for the disk. The disconnection issue remained.
And I've tried rebooting the laptop: the disconnection issue remained.


@FrankThomas thanks I don't have any issue with my dozens of external hard drives: only the internal hard drive that I'm mounting via the External Hard Drive Lay-Flat Docking Station has the issue.

I've run a similar setup (a 2 drive bay, with a pair of 14tb drives) with no issues. What's the rating of the power supply for the bay? That's about the only thing I can think of

@JourneymanGeek Thanks, the official manual on https://sabrent.com/products/ec-dflt?srsltid=AfmBOorHpS79dEgdUVrqNZV2ayjfpYPkf4XuSCABNHgZuNsPeHMeYk1z mentions the power is DC 12V/2.0A

That's about in line with what mine has - and well under what it needs https://www.seagate.com/content/dam/seagate/migrated-assets/www-content/product-content/enterprise-hdd-fam/exos-x22-channel/en-us/docs/203812000a.pdf

@JourneymanGeek thanks, good catch, I see 12V indeed, you're welcome to post as answer

Oh that's NOT the issue. I think I found it. Answer incoming.

Ok, ruling out the most obvious things - I think we can rule out spin up power, the power supply seems sufficient, and I've run a similar setup in a different dock with no issues. I'd also say at worst, It'd be unreliable but it'd work.
One possibility is that the drive is too large (capasitywise) for the dock, but that's a little tricky to troubleshoot. There's a common issue which I suspect is the case that's worth looking at.
Your disk runs a 'newer' version of sata than the dock supports and its a slightly unusual, but well-documented hardware issue. At some point, modern hard drives have gotten a particular pin remapped for power savings and some devices have problems with these.
The feature is called "PWDIS" and it was originally reserved, and tied into the 3.3v rail. Newer drives in an 'older' power setup will go to sleep if its there. Tom's hardware has a article going into details
The datasheet you provided confirms this

I'm not sure about the dock - but its likely
A common fix is to tape up pin 3 with kapton tape - which disables this 'feature' - its probably the best option since its reversible.

Thanks, nice find! I'll try the tape trick once I have some tape.

https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Fix-the-33V-Pin-Issue-in-White-Label-Disks-/ is useful further reading/watching - Interestingly my Exos x16s wasn't affected by this so I didn't have to do this personally.
